# DIfference between in regard(s) to vs with regard(s) to

Tags: grammar, sentence-choice

Can you tell me the difference between: in regard(s) to vs. with regard(s) to
and the plural "s" is needed or not?
For example: "I do not take any responsibility in regard(s) to the information contained in this text" or "I do not take any responsibility with regard(s) to the information contained in this text?
Or may be just "regarding" is much better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They tend to be used interchangeably. That's the short answer.

The traditional distinction was this:

Use the singular **regard** when the meaning is something like **with reference to** or **concerning**. This is the usage that your question describes.

Use the plural when the meaning is something like **fond wishes**.

The following illustrates these usages:

> I haven't spoken to Tom in years. When you see him, give him my regards.
>
> I have a few words to say in regard to the unauthorized use of the water cooler.

But please don't use **in regard to** as a crutch. You will sound like the insecure manager that no one likes. Wherever possible, use words like **about** and **concerning** instead.

> I have a few words to say about the unauthorized use of the water cooler.
>
> *Even better:*
>
> I want to discuss the unauthorized use of the water cooler.

Comment: Or "*I don't take any responsibility **for** the information contained in this text.*"